# Machine Leanring Test data

Tags: conv-neural-network

I am working on image classification.  For CNN image classification,  Can I use validation data as test data?   or should I split data into three ( train, validation, test )?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you use validation data for *model selection* to find the best model and/or hyperparameters. Test data is used to estimate *real world* performance for the best model from the model selection step. **You must not let any test data leak into the validation data and vice versa** as you will risk overfitting.

Basically:

1. When in training phase: train data
2. Model selection phase: validation data
3. Testing phase: then you can test your best model from the previous step on the test data to get a real world performance estimate.

All datasets should be nonoverlapping, and you should ideally not know about any properties of the test data.